# How to report exceptions in android project automatically to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, exception, firebase-crash-reporting

I've seen the option of automatic crash reports to firebase. But what about regular try/catch exceptions? Is there any way to set automatic logs to Firebase on each caught exception in my android app?

Comment: You almost certainly do *not* want every single caught exception to be reported in your app.  It would be overwhelming, depending on how many and what kind of third party libraries you're using.  It's better to selectively log individual exceptions that would be helpful for diagnosis, as Frank illustrates in his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you use the Firebase Crash Reporting SDK in your app, uncaught exception are automatically reported to the server.

To report an exception that you catch, cal `FirebaseCrash.report`:

```
  ...
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    FirebaseCrash.report(ex);
}
```

I highly recommend reading the [Firebase Crash Reporting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_your_first_error). It's pretty much a single page and covers the entire API and many common use-cases.

Comment: `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(ex)`